# Android Studio: undefined reference to `__system_property_get'

Tags: android-studio

I'm porting a project from Eclipse to Android Studio.

I'm getting the error undefined reference to `__system_property_get'. However, the old project builds just fine using Ant and Eclipse.

Is there anything I need to add to the ndk section of build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up commenting out the ndk section and adding a ndkBuild task.

```
// The normal ndk build (commented out above) is broken because __system_property_get can't be resolved
// by the linker. Doing the build via the ndk-build script is workaround.
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.library').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder()
commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build", '-C', 'src/main/jni',
        "NDK_OUT=$buildDir/ndk/obj",
        "NDK_APP_DST_DIR=$buildDir/../../../externalLibs"
}
assembleRelease.dependsOn ndkBuild
assembleDebug.dependsOn ndkBuild
```